# Kudan Android SDK: Is it possible to add image after marker is detected?

Tags: android, opengl-es, augmented-reality, kudan

I am developing an Android app based on `Kudan SDK`. On my AR screen, I have a button and `onclick` should download the image from the server, save it locally, and add the image to marker.

The issue is when my `ARActivity` opens, if I add the image as code below, inside setup method, it works but on button click if I use the same method I get the following error:

> [unnamed-7603-0] bindTextureImage: clearing GL error: 0x501

On log console and image doesn't show up.

```
ARTexture2D texture = new ARTexture2D();
texture.loadFromPath(testPath);
texture.setTextureID(1);
ARImageNode imageNode = new ARImageNode(texture);
trackable.getWorld().addChild(imageNode);
imageNode.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: This clearly sounds like a threading issue. OpenGLes expects all gl functions to be called from the same thread. Possibly in your case, you are calling the function from button event which can be a different thread.

Comment: Any sample code would be appreciated!

Comment: Just use a boolean flag like 'bool shouldShowImage' and make it true in the button event. Then in the draw function you can load and render the image.